# Issue working with a recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-imageview

I've got a problem using the recycler view on my android app. 
Everything works fine, until I add 4/5 rows to the recycler view. And application crashes.

This is the model of the recycler view, in the application I add dynamically Images and Text in the text view.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageIDEntryList"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_image_grey_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/entryNameRecycler"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:gravity="left|center"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="35dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageIDEntryList"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I'm using jpeg format to save the images on recycler view. 
Is the crash caused by the excessive size of the images?
I've also used a library (imagepicker) for manage images and put in the rows of recycler view.

this is the issue:

```
android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

this is where I add the image to imageView

```
if(requestCode == Keys.IMAGE_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final Uri imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(ImagePicker.getFirstImageOrNull(data).getPath()));
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

How is the crash caused?

Comment: That line you copied from your logs is not the issue. You're looking for [the stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173) from the crash, which should be a large section of red lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) for updating images in RecyclerView. These libraries are opensource and are much more efficient than using Bitmap.

With Picasso, you can load in ImageView as simple as

```js
Picasso.get().load(yourUri).into(imageView);
```

Also it will run efficiently making your recycler view scroll smoothly.